# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching <host> found

Tags: java, ssl, exception

My Java server is using a rest service to retrieve information. Every several months I get an exception from java:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name
>   matching  found.

This exception happens for few seconds and goes away until next time. From reading in the internet, I saw it's a problem of the remote server and its certificate. I talked to the support of the service but they say they updated the certificate on January and nothing was done regarding the certificate.

What/where else can I check or tell them to check in order to avoid this error?

Thanks

Comment: You could have been subjected to a man-in-the-middle attack, and the error correctly blocked the attack. --- To learn more, you should log the domain name, IP address and server certificate whenever that error occurs, so you can research what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You wrote "you should log the domain name, IP address and server certificate" - domain,ip and cert of what?

Comment: Of the server you're trying to connect to.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, I always call "https://example.com/api/" + api + "/" + item + "?api_token=...&fmt=json" so I "know" what I'm calling... how can I know if someone else "got through" and log him?

Comment: You know "example.com" (domain name), but I said to log it, in case your app connects to multiple servers. You still don't know which IP address that mapped to, or which certificate the server you're connecting to returned to you.

Comment: Ofcourse I don't but I also don't know how to log this. I make the call to example.com and java throws an exception so at this point I have nothing except the exception object.

Comment: I told you, as a *comment*, what you need in order to learn more. I didn't write an *answer*, because obtaining that information is not simple, and you should do your own research to figure out how to do it. I also couldn't tell you how, since you never said how you're doing this.